# ADOTable.Locate in Master-Detail Relationship

Tags: delphi, master-detail, locate, tadotable

I have a Master-Detail Relationship between two Tables , I Select a Record in Master Table and its Details shows in Detail Table , next i want to Locate in Detail Table Only in Details about Master Table`s Selected Record but when I use ADOTable.Locate(...) , it locates in all Records of Detail Table !
For Example I have this Tables :

Master :

ID |  Name

11 |  Mahmood
22 |  Maseoud

....

Detail :

UID | Pet(!)
11 | Cat
22 | Dog
22 | Cat

I have selected User "Mahmood" ( ID = 11) and in Detail Table only 1 Record shown with UID = 11 and Pet = Cat
Now I want to Locate on detail Table :
DetailTable.Locate('Pet', 'Dog', [])

"Locate" above returns " TRUE " whereas there is no Record with "Dog" value in details of Selected User

How can I solve this Problem ?
I want to Search in details of Selected Record in Master Table

Thanks before ...

Comment: I want to Locate Record that have this values : UID := 11 , Pet = Dog
Locate Should Return False when Record with ID = 11 is Selected in Master Table , but it Returns True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TCustomADODataSet.LocateRecord` works on an unfiltered clone, specify all relevant fields in your search:

```
DetailTable.Locate('UID; Pet', VarArrayOf([11, 'Dog']), [])
```